# Unity Rotate vs .rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am moving a transform, but I do not know which rotation to modify. Should I change the .rotation or use Rotate on a transform. Rotate() assigns an absolute orientation and .rotation adds a rotation to the current orientation.

```
transformToMove.Rotate(new Vector3(yDif, xDif, zDif));
```

vs

```
transformToMove.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
        currentRotation, 
        desiredRotation, 
        maxDeltaAngle
    );
```

which one is the correct one to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact rotation you want them to be, assign it directly to transform.rotation.  If you want them to turn a certain amount from whatever rotation they're at now, use transform.Rotate().

All transform.Rotate() is going to do is take their current rotation, add the amount you specify, and then assign it to tranform.rotation.